# Transparent GIF in IE6 displays BEHIND content

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, layout

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="pop" class="pop_komm">
    <img src="Graphics/list_updated.gif">
    </div>
```

This is the css:

```
.pop_komm {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 52px;
    width: 208px;
    left: 660px;
    display:none;
    top: 247px;
    zoom:1;
}
```

The above divs style.display is set to "block" using javascript on a drop-down lists onChange event.

The "pop" div is displayed, and the image in it, but the problem is that the image is displayed behind the content. This only happens in IE6 (haven't tested IE7 or 8 yet).
Other browsers display it fine.

The image is a transparent GIF, which I think might have something to do with it.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: (your image tag isn't closed)

Comment: Don't support IE6 unless you **really, really** have to. This browser **needs** to die ASAP.

Comment: img tags doesn't need any close tag unless doctype is xhtml if I am not mistaken...

Comment: Have you tried it with a jpg? What about setting the z-index?

.pop_komm img { z-index: 20;}

Or assign the image as the background of the div?

Comment: Anything but transparent gif displays fine...

Comment: @Camran - do you have a link?

Comment: @Camran : that's a pretty lazy comment. Unclosed tags can lead to errors (any type of error). Even if that's not the solution here (it may be, IDK), adding a little `/` won't kill you.

Comment: @Camran : Is the parent of `.pop_komm` is set to :`position: relative;z-index:1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does have some nasty issues with `z-index`.

The default value of the `position` style is `position:static;`. This value does not participate in `z-index` ordering, meaning that elements where you haven't specified the `position` style may not be layered as you expect.

The solution is to add `position:relative;` to any elements that are mis-behaving - ie the elements that are being layered above the image.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no layer above the div. just the body. I am not at work right now, but I will try to change the positions and z-index properties and see if it gets rid of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

add position relative to the image?